# How to add font awesome icons in active admin menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, font-awesome

I want to add font awesome icons to my active admin menus.

Please somebody help!

How can I add font awesome icons? I tried lots but didn't find the solution.

I am using active_admin_flat_skin.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to try the following

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
    menu.add :label => "<i class='fa fa-tachometer'></i> Dashboard".html_safe, :priority => 1
    menu.add :label => "Second Item", :priority => 2
    menu.add :label => "Third Item", :priority => 3
  end
end
```

If the `font-awesome` library imported then the try upper code.

It should work perfectly.

Hope it helps